# Updating two dictionary lists by keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary list which I wanted to update with the keys exsits.
I tried like below but it didn't work. Can someone please advice

```
dic1 =   [{"valid": 0, "correct": "abc", "other": ["aaa"]}]
dic2 =  [ {"correct": "morning", "other":["negative"]}] 

dict1.update(dic2)
```

Expected output:

```
[{"valid": 0, "correct": "morning", "other": ["negative"]}]
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but for formatting questions on stackoverflow: You can either put a single tick around code that is in a sentence `like this` or, for multiline, you can indent with 4 spaces or surround with 3 tickmarks. Don't combine them though. The easiest way to format for code, though, is to highlight the code and press the `{}` button at the top.

Comment: @JNevill : thanks, I'm new to this, so had some struggle with formatting

Comment: Actually, you trying to use `update` on `list`. It does not have an `update` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic1[0].update(dic2[0]) 
print(dic1)
```

Since you have only one element in the list .i.e. a dictionary.

```
#output
[{'correct': 'morning', 'other': ['negative'], 'valid': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def update(dic1, dic2):
    for i in dic1[0]:
        if i in dic2[0]:
            dic1[0][i] = dic2[0][i]
    return(dic1)

dic1 = update(dic1, dic2)
print(dic1)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

dic1 and dic2 are lists. You need to apply the `update` function on a **dictionary**. This should solve your problem:

```
dic1 =   {"valid": 0, "correct": "abc", "other": ["aaa"]}
dic2 =  {"correct": "morning", "other":["negative"]}
dic1.update(dic2)
print (dic1)
```